# Why bower components does not load - 404 - after injecting by wired and gulp

Tags: node.js, bower

I am injecting my scripts and stuff using gulp

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  var options = {
    bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
    directory: './bower_components',
    ignorePath: 'public'
  };
  var injectSrc = gulp.src(['./public/css/**/*.css', './public/js/**/*.js'], {
    read: false
  });
  var injectOptions = {
    ignorePath: 'public'
  };
  return gulp.src('./src/views/layout.pug').pipe(wiredep(options)).pipe(inject(injectSrc, injectOptions)).pipe(gulp.dest('./src/views'));
});
```

Then I expect it to be loaded by the server, but I've only got `404` status.

After thinking a while I got an idea, from previous project where my injected files were all in `/public/lib` folder. You know I don't like this convention and had no idea how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Then it hit me, it'a static files! So I just add the directive to my `index.js`

```
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```

Remember about first part, because otherwise browser will be looking one folder down in a tree...